# Change numeric vector into specific date

Tags: r

I have got a vector like `0 20 365 390` and would like to convert into the date that would occur if that many days has passed so for some origin day (`2007-01-01`) would be `2007-01-01 2007-01-21  2008-01-01 2008-02-26`. How would I quickly do that in R?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this like so:

```r
dat <- as.Date('2007-01-01') 
dat + c(0,20, 365, 390)
#> [1] "2007-01-01" "2007-01-21" "2008-01-01" "2008-01-26"
```

You will discover that the last element of the result is different to your expected output.

Comment: You might also supply `dat` as the `origin = ` operator, like `as.Date(c(0,20, 365, 390),origin = '2007-01-01')`

Answer (score 0):

Even though it is not necessary in this case when dealing just with days, it is always a good idea to point at the `lubridate` package when dealing with dates/time:

```
library(lubridate)

start_date <- as_date("2007-01-01")
my_vec <- c(0, 20, 365, 390)

start_date + days(my_vec)
#> [1] "2007-01-01" "2007-01-21" "2008-01-01" "2008-01-26"

# easily adding months:
start_date + months(my_vec)
#> [1] "2007-01-01" "2008-09-01" "2037-06-01" "2039-07-01"
```